Is it possible to find (or derive) a Land Surface Temperature product with a resolution of 50 metres or less?
I need to do a temperature assessment at a suburb level, hence the requirement for high resolution. The best I could find is 100m derived from Landsat, which apparently reaches a 30m res in the US. Is it possible to extrapolate that to the rest of the world? Are there other products?


Is it possible to find?

This is not something one can answer directly! So, Maybe! Depending on the availability and accessibility of high resolution thermal satellite data (commercially or publicly) which is also determined by the study region and period of interest.

Is it possible to derive?

Yes, but...
Landsat is probably the only publicly available, high-medium resolution,  consistent revisit, and  global coverage satellite with thermal bands (MODIS too, but it's more coarse resolution). The resolution of land surface temperature products based on Landsat matches the native resolution of the thermal infrared bands in Landsat satellites, which are 100, 60, and 120 meters for Landsat 8&9,  7, and 4&5 respectively (see here). Any higher resolution you might see based on these products involves resampling in one way or another.
Technically, you can achieve any desired resolution using resampling, but that doesn't mean the new higher resolution is accurate or even meaningful!
Almost all GIS/raster software provide tools to do resampling tasks (An example is the Resample tool in ArcGIS pro) and these tools vary in the underlying method and their complexity. Whether you resampled data yourself or found a resampled product, you need to account for the error and how resampling was done. See the answer of this similar question for more about the error involved.
Depending on the specific of your application, resampling in one way might be better than the other, but they all involve uncertainty and generally take one of two routes:
1-) You may assume that all new cells in the desired higher resolution have the same value of the overlapping cell in the original coarse resolution (No guarantee that this is the case in reality). This, although sounds trivial, might be beneficial for solving some spatial alignment issue, but it also involve the risk of spatial autocorrelation.
2-) You can try to interpolate the value of the new cells in the desired higher resolution based on ancillary data and the overlapping (and neighboring) cell in the original coarse resolution. The interpolation method can vary from well known simple method to more complex machine learning methods, and ideally, it should provide uncertainty estimation along with the new cell value.
